# "Mack the butcher" string with methods and arrays

Tags: javascript

Im playing with arrays and methods and functions and want to print the following string

Mack the butcher

```
var mack = [];


function newMack(){
mack.push("Mack", "the", "butcher");
mack.join(" ");

};

alert(newMack());
```

Im getting undefined and i dont know what im doing wrong.

here's live
https://jsfiddle.net/1hn5d05k/

Comment: A function always returns undefined, unless you tell it otherwise. It seems like you wanted to just `alert(mack)` instead.

Comment: There's no semicolon needed after the closing bracket when you declare a function that way.

Comment: Yea it was the return.. didn't know that it always returns undefined unless told. Functions are the only ones that confuse me so much and keep going back to understand how they work...

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate, but there's no tangible reason to downvote it (just so people know).

Answer (score 2):

Try to `return` the processed result from the function,

```
return mack.join(" ");
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1hn5d05k/1/)

If you do not return anything from a function which was called without `new` keyword then `undefined` will be returned. See the [documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1) here.